# Over 1000 files in this folder c:\windows\system32\config\txr

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp, terminal

Every now and then this issue arises, at some point (I think a remote login) to one of my terminal servers.
I see at once a hard disk that's almost full, research showed me the contents of this folder is over 1000 files, each 5 MB in size.
I'm unable to delete these files and after a restart there gone.

The files have al the same time, and I can only find a user login off one minute later.
Earlier I thought it occurred when a user logged on.

---

I would like to prevent it in the future, but when during the day this occurs again I would like to recover some of that 5 GB space this issue takes up.

That's what I ment with workaround, a reboot can only be done without users outside office hours, thats not making me happy as you can imagine.

regards Jeroen Ruijter

Comment: Windows search service.

Comment: Dear Brian, is there a work around to get this space back without a restart?

Comment: this has nothing to do with search. Those are data for Transactional Registry (doing registry operations in transactions)

Comment: I would try to isolate the reason this is happening, rather than trying to find a workaround.

Comment: I would like to prevent it in the future, but when during the day this occurs again I would like to recover some of that 5 GB space this issue takes up.

That's what I ment with workaround, a reboot can only be done without users outside office hours, thats not making me happy as you can imagine.

regards Jeroen Ruijter

Comment: How do you advise me to isolate this issue? It's not on a daily basis; I assume it's every time with another user during logon if I assumed this correctly.